# SSRS with Execution Account - Custom Connection Strings and Credentials Settings

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, rdl

We have a whole bunch of rdl files that we have published on a SQL 2005 Server Reporting Services. There is an execution account on the SSRS that has been setup which we use to retrieve the data for the reports. These existing rdl use a shared data source and have the "Credentials Not Required" option set. Because the execution account is set on the SSRS, the data source works without credentials from the user.

I am trying to add a new report which has to be in the same location as the other reports with a difference that it uses a custom connection string like this:

```
<DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <rd:DataSourceID>41caaa2-1111-2222-4444-466666666666</rd:DataSourceID>
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>="Data Source=" &amp; Parameters!dbServer.Value &amp; ";Initial Catalog=" &amp; IIf(Parameters!countryCode.Value = " ","SampleDB","SampleDB" &amp; Parameters!countryCode.Value)&amp;";Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=True;"</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
```

When creating this rdl I set the credential options as "Credentials not required" just like the shared data source used for the other reports. When I manually upload this rdl file to my SSRS the custom connection string remains intact and the credentials remain specified at "Credentials not required".

The issue is when we promote this file to our testing and production regions using a custom installer the custom connection string remains intact but the credential options changes to "Windows Authentication" or changes to "Credentials supplied by the user running the report". In our installer code we have a custom action written in C# that uses this to publish all rdl's to SSRS:

```
sql2005rs.ReportingService2005.CreateReport(namewithoutExtension, "/Reports List", true, definition, null);
```

Any suggestions on why the credentials option that I have set in my rdl gets overwritten? Is there any specific option that I need to provide in my custom connection string to make this work? I have also tried using a connection string without the Integrated Security option and having credentials not required enabled. The results are the same i.e. when the installer publishes the report it flips the credentials to "Windows Authentication" or "Credentials supplied by the user running the report".

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Regards
Ali.